Error al deployar el frontend en react
Se presenta este error en servidor web y en localhost no
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve "./components/Header/Header.jsx" from "src/App.jsx"
file: /vercel/path0/src/App.jsx
    at getRollupEror (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:375:41)
    at error (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:372:42)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18907:24)
    at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18867:26
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Revise las importaciones y estaba todo correcto.
import { Footer } from "./components/Footer/Footer.jsx"
import { Header } from "./components/Header/Header.jsx"
import { Principal } from "./Principal"

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Principal />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

Muchas Gracias

Hola Fast, el mensaje de error es bastante descriptivo, no puede encontrar el archivo "./components/Header/Header.jsx". Comproba que exista y esté bien escrito (mayusculas inclusive)
